# Unindent and move to previous line

Tags: visual-studio-2013, resharper-8.0

Let's say I have the following two lines of code, where `-` represents whitespace, and `|` represents my cursor.

```
var foo = FooBarBaz-----------------
--------------|.Xyzzy
```

Using Resharper 8.0 with Visual Studio 2013, how can I remove all the indicated whitespace to create the following line, quickly and without using my mouse?

```
var foo = FooBarBaz.Xyzzy
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Hold <kbd>Shift</kbd>, press the <kbd>Up</kbd> arrow, <kbd>End</kbd>
2. Press <kbd>Delete</kbd>

or

Press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Backspace</kbd>, then <kbd>Backspace</kbd>